# node.run_state giving ERROR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have created a ruby block within my recipe as follows:

```
ruby_block 'load_databag_secret' do
  block do
    value = data_bag_item("tokens", "masterkey", IO.read("/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret") )
    node.run_state['docker']['password'] = value['key']
  end
end
```

Now, I am trying to use `node.run_state['docker']['password']` as follows:

```
token2_hash = lambda { token1_hash.deep_merge({ "value" => node.run_state['docker']['password'] } ) }
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
ERROR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Please suggest correct way to use `node.run_state['docker']['password']`

Answer (score -1):

The run state is not like node attributes which auto-vivify undefined levels. More to the point it's an advanced internal feature that you probably shouldn't be using without more knowledge of Chef and context for how it works.

I've said this before to you and I'll say it again: stop asking these one-off questions on StackOverflow. You are clearly trying to accomplish something specific that reaches back over the dozen or so questions you've asked. This is not a good place for that, ask on IRC, Slack, or Discourse where the answerers can have unified context and a better idea of your actual goals.

Comment: i get your point. but all those sites are blocked on my company laptop :(

Comment: That is harsh, my usual recommendation in those cases is to make it clear to your boss and the higher ups that restricting access to Chef's volunteer support means they need to go buy a commercial support contract. If they aren't okay with that, they need to allow our volunteer support team to do its thang in the most efficient way as we don't have spare resources to offset their IT policy.